# How to upload an audio file in salesforce using android development?

Tags: android, api, rest, salesforce

I am using **SalesforceMobileSDK-Android** to develop an android application. I am able to develop a very basic android application, In my application, I am able to fetch the contact,account,lead etc details from the salesforce account and perform crud operation on these data.
In my android application,I have a button called **uploadFile**, Now want to upload an audio file on click of that button, I am not able to find any rest api which will help me to upload it on Salesforce from my android client application.

If there is any sample url or source code or any helpful resource please provide me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to experiment with `base64` encoding the file and sending a `POST`request to `/services/data/v26.0/sobjects/attachment/{parent record id}/body` endpoint. I haven't done it myself but there are some nice examples:

1. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm - uses different approach with json message.
2. http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2011/09/using-binary-data-with-rest.html - if you can create a server-side REST service.
3. Check resources on Salesforce-dedicated Stack site, for example https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1301/image-upload-to-chatter-post
4. Last but not least - check the Salesforce community boards, for example http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/APIs-and-Integration/inserting-an-attachment-via-REST/td-p/322699

Answer (score 0):

It's mostly server side you have to be concerned about when uploading files, client side you could have an approach like this (just get the idea, it's not a full functional code):

```
 FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(selectedPath) );
 // open a URL connection to the Servlet
 URL url = new URL(urlString);
 // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
 conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
 // Allow Inputs
 conn.setDoInput(true);
 // Allow Outputs
 conn.setDoOutput(true);
 // Don't use a cached copy.
 conn.setUseCaches(false);
 // Use a post method.
 conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
 conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
 conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);
 dos = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream() );
 dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
 dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name:\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + selectedPath + "\"" + lineEnd);
 dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
 // create a buffer of maximum size
 bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
 bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
 buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
 // read file and write it into form...
 bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
 while (bytesRead > 0)
 {
  dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
  bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
  bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
  bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
 }
 // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
 dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
 dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
 // close streams
 Log.e("Debug","File is written");
 fileInputStream.close();
 dos.flush();
 dos.close();
```